# How to have many optional routes in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

How can I make the possibility to accept the requests in different orders and with some optional parameters?

`https://localhost:44314/api/courses/page=2&pageSize=6&language=test&institution=test&area=test`

`https://localhost:44314/api/courses/page=2&pageSize=6&institution=test&area=test`

`https://localhost:44314/api/courses/page=2&pageSize=6&area=test&language=test`

I have tried as below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("page={page:int}&pageSize={pageSize:int}&language={language?}&institution={institution?}&area={area?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CourseViewModel>> ListCourses(int page, int pageSize, string language="", string institution="", string area="")
```

And I have the error as:

> System.ArgumentException: 'An optional parameter must be at the end of the segment. In the segment
>   'page={page}&pageSize={pageSize}&language={language?}&institution={institution?}&area={area?}',
>   optional parameter 'language' is followed by '&institution='.
>   Parameter name: routeTemplate'

Comment: In general the route template should only be used to match the URI path (i.e. the parts separated by /), not the URI query (i.e. the parts separated by &) as the former usually has a fixed order and but the latter shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the route template and the route table will use the parameters of the action for matching the route via query string in the requested URL

```
//GET api/courses?page=2&pageSize=6&language=test&institution=test&area=test
//GET api/courses?page=2&pageSize=6&institution=test&area=test
//GET api/courses?page=2&pageSize=6&area=test&language=test
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CourseViewModel>> ListCourses(int page, int pageSize, string language = "", string institution = "", string area = "")
```

In this case the order does not matter. Once they are present to be matched.

Comment: You were right, by adding the '?' it changed everything. It was missing on the url.